# Value comes up twice - PHP

Tags: php

I want to get a value but it comes up twice:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['user'];
    include 'connect.php';
    if (isset($_GET['var'])) {
        $var = $_GET['var'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $var;
        $pieces = explode(",", $var);

        foreach ($pieces as $i) {
            $sql    = "SELECT title FROM interests WHERE id = '$i' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        }
        $value = join(",", $row);

    }
    echo $username;
    echo $value;

?>
```

It comes up as: `result, result`; it should only come up as 1 result and not repeated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to turn some id's into words with that foreach function, and then I try to put all words into a line, separated by a "," . But when I have 1 id, it echoes the same word twice.

Comment: Can you show what you have in the `$pieces` and the MySQL Table?

Comment: MySQL table under "interests" I've got an id, a title and a description
and $pieces is supposed to be an array with the results from the query, so it should be 1,2,3 because the var in the link is (in the .php?var=1,2,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns both a numerically indexed and associative array all in one. This means you get two copies of every field in the same array (one indexed by a number and one indexed by name). Change the call to this to only get an associative array:

```
$row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

With regards your second problem discussed in the comments below, try this:

```
        $titles = [];
        foreach ($pieces as $i) {
            $sql    = "SELECT title FROM interests WHERE id = '$i' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $titles[] = $row["title"];
        }
        $value = join(",", $titles);
```

Comment: It now shows the result alone , not doubled. But if my var = 1,2 it doesn't give me both corresponding words to those id's, it only gives me the first one.

Comment: @BadinaFilip It was probably always doing that because you overwrite `$row` each time your `foreach` loop runs. `$row` will only ever be an array of one value.

Comment: And is there a way to take that array and add any new values to it?

Comment: @BadinaFilip Yes, but since you can't put code in comments see the edit at the bottom of my answer.